# Are my JPanel instances being disposed of (and why?)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

In my code, my main class creates a JFrame, and then instantiates a bunch of Players and puts them in an ArrayList. Then it creates a bunch of Cards (which are JPanels) and adds them to an  ArrayList for each player. The problem is that after all of this, the JFrame only has one card component even though they were each added to the JFrame in the Card's constructor.

These cards are still in the ArrayList of cards for each player but aren't in the JFrame.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Uno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Uno g = new Uno(2, 6);
    }
    private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    public static Uno uno;
    private static GuiUno gui;

    public Uno(int numPlayers, int initialCards) {
        gui = new GuiUno();
        gui.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            players.add(new Player(i));
        }
        for (Player p : players) {
            for (int i = 0; i < initialCards; i++) {
                p.drawCard(p.randCard());
            }
        }

    }

    public static GuiUno getGUI() {
        return gui;
    }

    public void addCardToGUI(Card c) {
        gui.add(c);
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }
}

class Card extends JPanel {

    private static Font font;
    private static FontMetrics metrics;
    private int number;
    private Player p;
    private Color color;
    private int x, y;

    public Card(Player p, int number, Color color) {
        if (font == null) {
            this.font = GuiUno.font.deriveFont((float) 12);
        }
        this.number = number;
        this.color = color;
        this.p = p;
        updateCoords();
        Uno.getGUI().add(this);
        System.out.println(color.toString() + " " + number + " " + x + " " + y);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(50, 77);
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    private String getText() {
        if (number > 0) {
            return String.valueOf(number);
        } else {
            switch (number) {
                case -1:
                    return "Wild";
                case -2:
                    return "+2 Draw";
                case -3:
                    return "Skip";
                case -4:
                    return "Reverse";
                case -5:
                    return "+4 Wild";
            }
        }
        return String.valueOf(number);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void updateCoords() {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        switch (p.POS) {
            //top
            case 0:
                x += 15;
                y += 15;
                x += 50 * p.getHand().size();
                break;
            //bottom
            case 1:
                x += 15;
                y += Uno.getGUI().getContentPane().getHeight() - 15;
                x += 50 * p.getHand().size();
                break;
            //left
            case 2:
                x += 15;
                y += 15;
                y += 77 * p.getHand().size();
                break;
            //right
            case 3:
                x += Uno.getGUI().getContentPane().getWidth() - 15;
                y += 15;
                y += 77 * p.getHand().size();
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("" + x + " " + y);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (metrics == null) {
            metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        }
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.fillRect(x, y, 50, 77);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.setFont(this.font);

        g2.drawString(getText(), (x + 3), y + 19);
        AffineTransform orig = g2.getTransform();
        g2.rotate(Math.PI, x + 48, y + 66);
        g2.drawString(getText(), (x + 48), y + 66);
        g2.setTransform(orig);

    }
}

class GuiUno extends JFrame {

    public static Font font;
    Container pane;

    public GuiUno() {
        try {
            this.font = Font.createFont(Font.PLAIN, new File("tahoma.ttf"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Missing font file tahoma.ttf");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        this.setTitle("Uno");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}

class Player {

    private boolean human;
    private ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public final int POS;

    public Player(int i) {
        this.POS = i;
    }

    public void drawCard(Card c) {
        hand.add(c);

    }

    public ArrayList<Card> getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public Card randCard() {
        Card c = new Card(this, 5, Color.BLACK);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are adding multiple components to a JFrame (actually its contentPane in reality) in a default way and have not changed the layout manager, they are being added to a BorderLayout-using container in the BorderLayout.CENTER position, and thus each one added will cover the last. The solution is to use other layouts  or combinations of JPanels and layouts.
- You wish to show your Players playing on a game table, and so will need to figure out how to distribute your Player JPanels in the main JPanel. I'm not sure if you want them all lined up in a row or around a round or regular geometric table, but that's what you'll have to figure out first.
- I would create non-GUI logic classes first, classes that encapsulate the logic behind playing cards, decks, games, players, and then create corresponding GUI components to display the logical components.
- My Card GUI would not be a JPanel but rather a JLabel that displays an ImageIcon.

As an aside, I see an over-use of static modifiers in your code as well as what appears to be overly complex code, increasing what is known as the "cyclomatic complexity" of your program making it hard to debug and enhance.